# How to fetch endpoint of API with decorator function

Tags: python, flask

I'm implementing a login check (IAM is keycloak) with a decorator function on a Flask API.
There will be a separate endpoint ( `/rt_group1/.../rt_group99/` ) for each user, let's say 100 in total.
I would like to prevent that I have to write 100 decorator functions.
Instead, I want to 'fetch' the endpoint inside the decorator function, and then compare in a database if the requesting user matches the appropriate endpoint.

the decorator:

```
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)    
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):       
        user_session = get_token()
        if  user_session......
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return 'Not logged in'
    return wrapper
```

routing:

```
@app.route("/rt_group1/", endpoint='route1')
@login_required
def render_dashboard():
    return redirect('/rt_group1/')
```

Any ideas how to get `/rt_group1/` into the wrapper function?

Comment: Why don't you use something like `/rt_group/<user_key>` and get the user_key parameter as query parameter? I believe it is better design.

Comment: What's the difference then? I still need to hardcode <user_key> in the route and pass it to the wrapper. Or am i missing something?

Comment: user_key will be the parameter. If the login user is 1, you will call rt_group/1, if it is the 50, call rt_group/50. I mean there is no hardcode, you just pass the parameter and parameter's value is the user's login name.

Comment: Could you post your solution with code?